# TgWebApp MainButton working not correctly

Tags: angular, typescript

the main Button works only if I go only to its router, but it does not work if I go from the main page to the router where it is

```
`export class WelcomeComponent implements OnInit {
  pizzass!: PizzaAbout[];
  pizzas: PizzaInterface[] = [];

  private pizzasSubscription$!: Subscription;

  addToCartMar(pizza: PizzaInterface) {
    this.cartService.getItem(pizza);

    this.http.post('http://77.105.172.169:8000/pizzas', JSON.stringify(pizza));
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.pizzasSubscription$.unsubscribe();
  }

  close() {
    WebApp.close();
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.pizzass = pizzas;
    WebApp.ready();
    this.pizzasSubscription$ = this.cartService
      .sendPizza()
      .subscribe((pizzas: PizzaInterface[]) => {
        this.pizzas = pizzas;
      });
  }
  constructor(private cartService: CartService, private http: HttpClient) {}
}`
```

welcome component

```
tyleUrls: ['./feedback.component.scss'],
})
`export class FeedbackComponent {
  form = this.fb.group({
    city: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
    street: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
    organization: ['', [Validators.required]],
  });
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.checkInputs();
  }
  sendCallback = () => {
    const data = {
      city: this.form.controls.city.value,
      street: this.form.controls.street.value,
      organization: this.form.controls.organization.value,
    };
    WebApp.sendData(JSON.stringify(data));
  };
  checkInputs(): void {
    const street = this.form.controls.street;
    const city = this.form.controls.city;

    if (street || city) {
      WebApp.MainButton.setParams({
        text: 'Отправить',
      });
      WebApp.MainButton.show();
      WebApp.offEvent('mainButtonClicked', this.sendCallback);
      WebApp.onEvent('mainButtonClicked', this.sendCallback);
    } else {
      WebApp.MainButton.hide();
      WebApp.offEvent('mainButtonClicked', this.sendCallback);
    }
  }
}`
```

feedback component

```
`
export class UserComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
  pizzasSubscription$!: Subscription;
  pizzas: PizzaInterface[] = [];

getTotalPrice(items: PizzaInterface[]) {
    return items.reduce((acc, pizza) => {
      return (acc += pizza.price);
    }, 0);
  }
  constructor(private cartService: CartService) {}
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const data = {
      queryId: WebApp.initDataUnsafe.query_id,
      pizzas: this.pizzas,
      totalPrice: this.getTotalPrice(this.pizzas),
    };

    this.WebApp.onEvent('mainButtonClicked', () => {
      this.WebApp.sendData(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
    this.WebApp.offEvent('mainButtonClicked', () => {
      this.WebApp.sendData(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.WebApp.ready();
    this.pizzasSubscription$ = this.cartService
      .sendPizza()
      .subscribe((pizzas: PizzaInterface[]) => {
        this.pizzas = pizzas;
        if (pizzas.length == 0) {
          WebApp.MainButton.hide();
        } else {
          WebApp.MainButton.show();
          WebApp.MainButton.setParams({
            text: оплатить ${this.getTotalPrice(pizzas)},
          });
        }
      });
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.pizzasSubscription$.unsubscribe();
  }

  protected readonly WebApp = WebApp;
}`
```

user component

the main Button works only if I go only to its router, but it does not work if I go from the main page to the router where it is.. What am I doing wrong?

bot ts

```
bot.on('message', async (msg: Message) => {
  const chatId: number = msg.chat.id;
  const message: string | unknown = msg.text;
  if (message === '/start') {
    await bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'заполните форму', {
      reply_markup: {
        keyboard: [[{ text: 'заполнить форму', web_app: { url: webAppForm } }]],
      },
    });
    await bot.sendMessage(
      chatId,
      'Нажми на кнопку ниже, чтобы заполнить форму',
      {
        reply_markup: {
          inline_keyboard: [
            [{ text: 'перейти в магазин', web_app: { url: webApp } }],
          ],
        },
      }
    );
    await bot.sendMessage(
      chatId,
      'Нажми на кнопку ниже, чтобы заполнить форму',
      {
        reply_markup: {
          inline_keyboard: [
            [{ text: 'перейти в магазин', web_app: { url: webApp } }],
          ],
        },
      }
    );
  }
  if (msg.web_app_data?.data) {
    try {
      const data = JSON.parse(msg.web_app_data?.data);
      await bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'thanks for order');
      await bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Ваш город ' + data.city);
      await bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Ваша улиа ' + data.street);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
});

app.post('/pizzas', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { queryId, pizzas, totalPrice } = req.body;
  console.log(req.body);

  try {
    await bot.answerWebAppQuery(queryId, {
      type: 'article',
      title: 'успешно оплачено',
      input_message_content: {
        message_text: 'успешно оплачено' + totalPrice,
      },
    });
    pizzaArray = pizzas;
    res.sendStatus(200).send(pizzas);
  } catch (e) {
    await bot.answerWebAppQuery(queryId, {
      type: 'article',
      title: 'неудалось',
      input_message_content: {
        message_text: 'Неудалось произвести оплату',
      },
    });
    res.sendStatus(500).send({});
  }
});
app.get('/pizzas', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.status(200).send(pizzaArray);
});

app.listen(8080, () =>
  console.log(`server started on address http://localhost:8080`)
);
```